# How to drop duplicates in Workshop Object table

Tags: object, ontology, palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

in a Workshop App, can duplicates (based on some specific columns) be eliminated from an Object Table? And how?

Answer (score 1):

When I see a question like this, it is normally a hint that you may want a more expressive data model. For instance, if each object has a "category" property and you want to make a table of categories with a count of objects in each category you could:

a) Use a pivot table widget on the primary object
b) Create a new "category" object type linked to each object. Then make a regular object table and have a derived property counting the linked objects.

This can add some flexibility, though it has it's own limitations. You'll be able to easily go from categories -> linked objects, but if you have more the 100k objects and try to search around to the linked categories, you'll hit a limitation. So whether this approach works will depend on the semantics and scale of your data model.